# Ciclo for c# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, bucle-for, datagridview

¿Cómo hago un **ciclo for** que me vaya acumulando o guardando datos traídos desde **SQLServer** para luego mostrarlos? 
Es decir, cargo un **DataGridView** con datos de **SQLServer**. Lo que necesito es que al seleccionar  un **CheckBox** o varios se vayan guardando y/o acumulando ciertos datos de ese item seleccionado en un **ciclo for** con un **Array**.

**Formulario:**

```
            namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form{
        int contador = 0;
        public Form1(){
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
            llenarId();
            //dtgId.ReadOnly = true;
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk= new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            chk.HeaderText = "Seleccione";
            chk.Name = "check";
            dtgId.Columns.Add(chk);
        }

        public void llenarId(){
            try{
                string cadena = "cadena";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadena)){
                    con.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT id FROM clientes GROUP BY id";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    dtgId.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex){
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            //Codigo para enviar SMS
            string usuario = "usuario";
            string clave = "contraseña";
            string respuesta = "";
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text); 
            string telefono = txtNumero.Text;
            string texto = txtTexto.Text;
            List<Datos> item = new List<Datos>();
            Datos datos = new Datos(telefono, texto);
            item.Add(datos);
            contador++;
            string bloque = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++){
                //bloque += item[i].toString();
                bloque += bloque + "ID" + Convert.ToInt32(contador) + "\t" + item[i].celular + "\t" + texto + "\n";
            }

            Uri uri = new Uri("uri");

            HttpWebRequest requestFile = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            requestFile.Method = "POST";
            requestFile.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            postData.Append("api=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1") + "&");
            postData.Append("usuario=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(usuario) + "&");
            postData.Append("clave=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clave) + "&");
            postData.Append("separadorcampos=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("tab") + "&");
            postData.Append("bloque=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(bloque) + "&");

            //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(postData.ToString());
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

            requestFile.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream requestStream = requestFile.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse webResp = requestFile.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            if (requestFile.HaveResponse){
                if (webResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || webResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted){
                    StreamReader respReader = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
                    respuesta = respReader.ReadToEnd();
                    MessageBox.Show(respuesta);
                }
            }
        }

        private void dtgId_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
            var row = dtgId.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            var id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["id"].Value.ToString());
            try{
                string conn = "cadnena";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn)){
                    con.Open();
                    string sql = "SELECT id,celular FROM clientes WHERE id=@id";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read()){
                        txtId.Text = reader["id"].ToString();
                        txtNumero.Text = reader["celular"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }catch (SqlException exc){
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En tu código de Formulario, de donde salen los parámetros id, telefono, texto que pasas al constructor de Datos()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que estás definiendo un `List<Datos>`, es mejor que lo recorras con un **`foreach`**.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
        List<Datos> item = new List<Datos>();
        Datos datos = new Datos(id, telefono, texto);
        item.Add(datos);

        // string bloque = "ID" + id + "\t" + telefono + "\t" + texto + "\n";

        string bloque = string.Empty;
        foreach (Datos dato in item)
        {
            bloque += dato.toString();
        }
```

Aun así, ya que cada vez que pasas por este código vuelves a definir un nuevo objecto `List<Datos> item = new List<Datos>();`, tu lista siempre contendrá un solo elemento.

Prueba a definir la variable `List<Datos> item` a nivel de Clase. Así por lo menos estará activa mientras tengas abierto el Formulario:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{
    int contador = 0;
    // Defínela aquí
    List<Datos> item = new List<Datos>();

    public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ....
```

Y luego la utilizas en el evento `button2_Click` normalmente:

```
    // List<Datos> item = new List<Datos>();
    Datos datos = new Datos(id, telefono, texto);
    item.Add(datos);

    // string bloque = "ID" + id + "\t" + telefono + "\t" + texto + "\n";

    string bloque = string.Empty;
    foreach (Datos dato in item)
    {
        bloque += dato.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Entiendo, verás el DataGridView ya me trae cargado los datos de SQL, aún así ¿Es necesario que cree un método como dijiste?

Comment: No lo se, depende de tu código. Lo que te digo es que tal y como lo has puesto, no funcionaría. La variable item siempre tendrá 1 elemento.

Comment: Vale, ya lo he hecho

Comment: Te digo lo mismo, la Lista `List<Datos> item = new List<Datos>()` siempre tendrá 1 elemento. Entonces mi pregunta: ¿por que quieres recorrerla con un for?

Comment: Porque pensé que me guardaría todos los datos que necesitara, tal como el celular en este caso

Comment: Necesito que por cada item que yo seleccione se almacene ese celular en una variable para luego enviar mensajes de manera masiva

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo He modificado la respuesta, échale un vistazo.

Comment: Hmm, no. No me ha funcionado, al hacerlo así no me está enviando los mensajes. Para que se entienda lo que quiero hacer creo que debes ver esto: [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/301586/capturar-el-id-de-una-o-varias-celdas-de-un-datagridview-para-sms-masivos)